# Proving the elements of sets are equal

Tags: logic

I have to logically prove

> $ \{b,c\} = \{d\} \implies (b=c) ~ \wedge (c =d)$

I started with 
$$ (\forall x)(x \in \{b,c\} \implies x \in \{d\}  ) $$
$$ (b \implies d) ~\wedge (c \implies d) $$

However, I am not sure how to logically change the implication into equality and moreover, how to get the required result.

Comment: What does $b \implies d \wedge c \implies d$ mean?

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing it out. Edited.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't pointing out a typo. It doesn't make sense to say that $b \implies d$ unless $b$ and $d$ are logical formulae (are they? or are they just elements of a set?). I'm not sure what you're trying to convey with that line. To prove the statement in question you could note that $x \in \{b, c\} \iff (x = b \vee x = c\}$.

Comment: Okay thanks for suggestion. From there I can move to $$ (x = b ~\land x= c  \implies x = d)  $$ and from there to $$ (x = b  \implies x = d ~\land x= c  \implies x = d)  $$ I used $\land$ because it's true for all x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $\{b,c\}=\{d\}$ is equivalent to $\forall x~(x\in\{b,c\}\leftrightarrow x\in\{d\})$ by definition of set equality.

You also need premises that $\forall x~(x\in\{b,c\}\leftrightarrow (x=b\vee x=c))$ and $\forall x~(x\in\{d\}\leftrightarrow x=d)$ by definition of set construction.

Now generalise to an arbitrary term $a$, raise a few assumptions, use the general biconditionals, and eliminate equalities.

$$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{\{b,c\}=\{d\}}{\forall x~(x\in\{b,c\}\leftrightarrow (x=b\vee x=c))\\\forall x~(x\in\{d\}\leftrightarrow x=d)\\\hdashline\forall x~(x\in\{b,c\}\leftrightarrow x\in\{d\})\\\fitch{[a]}{a\in \{b,c\}\leftrightarrow a\in d\\a\in \{b,c\}\leftrightarrow (a=b\vee a=c)\\a\in\{d\}\leftrightarrow a=d\\\fitch{a=b}{a=b\vee a=c\\\quad\vdots\\a=d}\\b=d\\\quad\vdots\\c=d\\(b=d)\wedge(c=d)}\\(b=d)\wedge(c=d)}$$

Answer (score 2):

let $S = \{b, c\}$ and $T = \{d\}$ and assume $S = T$.

Then we have if $x \in S$, then $x \in T$. Thus we have $b \in T$. Since the only element in T, is $d$, we have $b = d$. This is by the definition of set inclusion. It follows then that $c = d$ so we have $ b = d$ and $c = d$. Thus by transivity of equality, we have $b = c$.

Comment: I was hoping for an answer that makes use of propositional logic syntax.

Comment: @mathnoob123 - What do you mean by "making use of propositional logic syntax"?